# How can I make a query (SQL) with two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a database like in the attached picture

[image]

I want to make a query that will display:

| Home | Away | Score home | Score away | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TeamName1 | TeamName3 | 3 | 2 | 2023-03-15 |
| TeamName2 | TeamName1 | 0 | 1 | 2023-03-10 |
| TeamName3 | TeamName2 | 2 | 2 | 2023-03-09 |
| TeamName1 | TeamName4 | 4 | 3 | 2023-03-13 |

Please help. Thank you in advance.

I'm learning sql and I can't deal with this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the input table structure, you should use [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) operator to get home and away team name for the result.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    h.name as home,
    a.name as away,
    g.score_home,
    g.score_away,
    g.date
FROM
    games g
JOIN
    team h
ON
    g.id_team_home = h.id_team
JOIN
    team a
ON
    g.id_team_away = a.id_team
```